# Run Function on Load and Hide Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want javascript to run the below function immediately after loading and when the user selects any other choice. The function below will hide some fields and show some fields depending on the user choice.

If the user should select 'cash', it should hide other fields, but if the user should select 'gift', it should show other fields.

```js
    function TakeOff() {

     if(document.getElementById('id_six_to').options[
         document.getElementById('id_six_to').selectedIndex].value == "cash") {
         document.getElementById('id_name').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('id_address').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('id_details').style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
         document.getElementById('id_name').style.display = '';
         document.getElementById('id_address').style.display = '';
         document.getElementById('id_details').style.display = '';
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('id_six_to').onchange = TakeOff;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id_six_to">Mytake</label><select name="six_to" id="id_six_to" class="form-control" title="">
   <option value="cash" selected>Cash</option>

  <option value="gift">Gift</option>

  </select></div>

  <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_name">Name</label><select name="name" title="" required class="form-control" id="id_name">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="a">a</option>

  <option value="b">b</option>

  <option value="c">c</option>

  </select></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_address">Address</label><input type="text" name="address" title="" id="id_address" readonly maxlength="10" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" /></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="id_details">Details</label><input type="text" name="details" title="" id="id_details" maxlength="200" placeholder="" class="form-control" /></div> 

        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger repo" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

By default, 'cash' is selected from the option and when I load the url of the form, instead of javascript to hide all other fields because 'cash' has been selected by default, it will show the fields that are not related to the 'cash' value.

I want to hide the 3 fields by default because 'cash' has been selected.

Comment: You have a huge load of typos and mispellings in your code, specifically the IDs of your elements.

Comment: thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you limited to only vanilla javascript, or can you use jQuery? What is your problem currently? YOu haven't specified any issues. Clearly this is "not working" but where are you stuck, are you getting any errors? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: By default, 'cash' is selected from the option and when I load the url of the form, instead of javascript to hide all other fields because 'cash' has been selected by default, it will show the fields that are not related to the 'cash' value. Hope you get my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire the function that sets the state of things when the select value changes...

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('id_six_to').onchange = TakeOff;
    TakeOff(); // add this so it runs at startup
};
```

Comment: Heh you're welcome.  That's exactly how I always do screen setups that the user can change.